# System out of memory exception when loading an excel spreadsheet with 100000+ rows with 25 columns or more to a gridview

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

i have to load a gridview with a huge amount of data 100k rows and about 27 columns. the datatable gives me a system out of memory exception error everytime i load it and then try to bind the gridview which is posted below.

What I have tried:

i have done research for about 2 weeks now and nothing has helped. can someone please give me a proper answer as to what i need to do? 
The below is what i do to load the spreadsheet directly into a dataset which is giving me the system out of memory exception. But now i would like to use an access database.

```
Public Function loadExcel()
        If GlobalVariable.outputSelectBackButtonFlag = True Then
            BindData()
        Else
            ''loadExcel Function to show the file to the gridView.
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim DtSet As New System.Data.DataSet("TaskList")
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim taskTable As New DataTable("TaskList")

            Dim filePath = Path.Combine(GlobalVariable.savedPath, GlobalVariable.excelFileName)
'Code to Use an Oledb Connection to get data from the Excel File
            If File.Exists(filePath) Then
                MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;';")
                MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
                DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
                GridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
                Session("TaskTable") = DtSet
                BindData()
                MyConnection.Close()
            Else
                Response.Redirect("UploadFile.aspx", True)
            End If
            Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: You have something else wrong somewhere because a DataTable can hold 16,777,216 rows.  If it has lots of long text, you could run out that way.  You can also load in batches too though.  BTW a sure way to get DVs is to command everyone not to DV.  Also, what does this have to do with access-vba???

Comment: @RickS i am really unsure on how to page.

Comment: Your title and your question don't match.  Are you trying to load data into an access database or display all the items of a spreadsheet on a datagrid?

Comment: @Plutonix i am not sure why i am getting a system out of memory exception on my local and my server. i'm really confused.

Comment: You are creating and not using several objects there and you should also turn on Option Strict.  Then try loading the rows maybe 10k at a time.  Paging or batching that way, I'd clean up the code so it tidys up after itself

Comment: @RickS i updated my title. thank you.

Comment: @Plutonix how would i be able to page 1k rows at a time. especially with the code above is that possible?

Comment: Use the Fill method that is overloaded to take a start and maxRecords parameter.  You should rework that code significantly though

Comment: You really answered your own question when you said "huge amount of data" Whenever you think that you should also be thinking.. how am I going to spoon feed this to the user so I don't kill the system and overwhelm the user.. Especially with a web based application, think about how many people may be trying to pull all that data at one time. @Plutonix has your answer.

Comment: @Trevor how would i be able to page and give them a fill with a max parameter i am really lost any help would do guys with code

Comment: @Plutonix how would i be able to rework it? i am really lost a beginner to .net so really confused on how to work this!

Comment: You send a page worth of data that has a form that includes a hidden field which you preset to indicate the next pages record position and a button that says  "NEXT PAGE" that submits the form. You probably would want to do the same for PREVIOUS PAGE too. Then at the server end check for NEXT PAGE button pressed and use that field to index to the next block of records.

Comment: By design, the DataTable will accumulate rows, so there is no need for 'Previous' unless you clear the DataTable rows.  You could also probably get better performance moving the data into a proper DB.

Comment: @Plutonix my first idea is to use a database. i would be able to add 100k + rows and 27+ columns to an access database using a datatable or a data reader? which would be better to insert rows?

Comment: @Plutonix thank you once again for the maxRecords parameter idea. you're a life saver especially with paging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try not loading all the data at once. It will help with memory issues.

Comment: yes i am using paging loading 1k records in each page.